# Batch File To Play A Song

Tags: batch-file, audio

I have a bit of a situation, I need to make a batch file play a song on a program  I have made, but here is the catch, I need the player to be invisible, you must not see it, is there any way of doing this so the song will play once the end?

Thanks :D

Comment: Apparently you don't want to just start the player minimized, right?  You want it to be *hidden*.  Did you write the program that plays the song?  Does it self terminate when it is done playing the song?

Comment: I guess it would be okay if the window was minimized.Yes the program does self terminate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a Bat/VBS to play an audio file :

```dos
@echo off
set file=track12.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

Comment: How can we make this loop itself?

Answer (score 3):

`wv_player` is a freeware player that can play audio media from a command prompt.

http://www.webxpace.net/

Answer (score 3):

Or use this, in bat/c#

**MasoPlayerEvolusion.bat**

```
/*
@echo off & cls
title MasoPlayerEvolusion                                             autor= Delmar
color 1a
:: Visitem o http://dbatchscript.forumeiros.com/
echo carregando aguarde...
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /S ^"%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\csc.exe^"') do set csc=%%i
if /i "%csc%"=="" EXIT
cls
:7
%csc% /nologo /out:"%tmp%\%~n0.exe" %0
cls 
mode 66,27
:menu
ECHO  ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo  º±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±º 
echo  º±²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²±º 
ECHO  º±²²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²²±º 
echo  º±²²±ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿±²±ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿±²²±º 
echo  º±²²±º[MasoPlayerEvolusion]            º±²±º  Masosoft©  º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ±²±ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ±²²±º 
echo  º±²²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²²±º 
echo  º±²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²±º 
echo  º±²²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²²±º 
echo  º±²²±ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»±²²±º 
echo  º±²²±º                                                   º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±º[1]."Procurar musica"                              º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±º[2]."Volume"                                       º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±º[3]."Parar"                                        º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±º[4]."Sair"                                         º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±º                                                   º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±º Escolha uma op‡Æo e de #Enter#                    º±²²±º
echo  º±²²±ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼±²²±º 
echo  º±²²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²²±º 
echo  º±²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²±º 
echo  º±²²±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±²²±º 
echo  º±²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²±º 
echo  º±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±º 
ECHO  ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
echo     ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ                                         ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ
set /p choice=:
if %choice% equ 1 goto Abrir
if %choice% equ 2 goto Volume
if %choice% equ 3 goto Parar
if %choice% equ 4 goto Sair
echo Invalid choice. & pause & goto menu

:Abrir
cls
@echo off
title MasoPlayerEvolusion                                                autor= Delmar
echo Iniciando...
cls
(
echo Dim executar
echo set executar = createobject("wscript.shell"^)
echo executar.run "%tmp%\%~n0.exe", vbhide
)>%tmp%\run.vbs
taskkill /F /IM %~n0.exe 2>nul
::del "%tmp%\%~n0.exe" >NUL 2>&1
CScript %tmp%\run.vbs //nologo > nul

cls
goto menu
cls
:Volume
@echo off
::Win xp
SNDVOL32.EXE 2>nul
::Win 7 ultimate
SNDVOL.EXE 2>nul
cls
goto menu

:Parar
@echo off
cls
taskkill /F /IM %~n0.exe 2>nul
cls
goto menu
:Sair
@echo off
cls
taskkill /F /IM %~n0.exe 2>nul
exit
*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Program
{
    public static string filePath;//variavel global
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string Cmd, StringBuilder StrReturn, int ReturnLength, IntPtr HwndCallback);
    [STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args) {
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Title = "Choose few files";
            dlg.Filter = "Media File(*.mpg,*.dat,*.avi,*.wmv,*.wav,*.mp3,*.flv)|*.wav;*.mp3;*.flv;*.mpg;*.dat;*.avi;*.wmv|AllFiles|*.*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            filePath = dlg.FileName;
        }
    if (args.Length < 0) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Usage: Nomeplayer [music.mp3]");
    return;
   }
        string FileName = @filePath;
        Console.WriteLine("Para parar tecle #Enter# " + FileName);
        string CommandString = "open " + "\"" + FileName + "\"" + " type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        Application.DoEvents();
        Console.ReadKey();
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

is in portuguese brazil

Comment: SO answers should be in English

Answer (score 0):

A batch Music Player !
 **Batch Music Player.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set vbsfile=%temp%\Intro.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
Set MyFile=%~f0
Set ShorcutName=DJ Batch Music Player
(
echo Call Shortcut("%MyFile%","%ShorcutName%"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split(CheminApplication,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(CheminApplication^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Start /Wait %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Del %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
::****************************************************************************************************
Title DJ Batch Music Player by Hackoo 2015
:menuLOOP
Color 0A & Mode con cols=78 lines=25
echo(
echo        ===============================================================
echo        "/  |  /  |                    /  |                          ";
echo        "$$ |  $$ |  ______    _______ $$ |   __   ______    ______  ";
echo        "$$ |__$$ | /      \  /       |$$ |  /  | /      \  /      \ ";
echo        "$$    $$ | $$$$$$  |/$$$$$$$/ $$ |_/$$/ /$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$  |";
echo        "$$$$$$$$ | /    $$ |$$ |      $$   $$<  $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |";
echo        "$$ |  $$ |/$$$$$$$ |$$ \_____ $$$$$$  \ $$ \__$$ |$$ \__$$ |";
echo        "$$ |  $$ |$$    $$ |$$       |$$ | $$  |$$    $$/ $$    $$/ ";
echo        "$$/   $$/  $$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/  $$$$$$/   $$$$$$/  ";
echo        "                                                            ";
echo        "                                                            ";
echo(       =============================Menu==============================
echo(
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo                         %%A  %%B
echo(
echo(       ===============================================================
set choice=
echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[1] Play DJ Buzz Radio
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching DJ Buzz Radio ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs
Set URL=http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[2] Play David Guetta Mix
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching David Guetta Mix ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\David_Guetta_Miami.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/David_Guetta_Miami_2014.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[3] Play Ibiza Mix
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching Ibiza Mix ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\IbizaMix.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/IbizaMix.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[4] Play Avicii Mega Mix
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching Avicii Megamix ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\IbizaMix.vbs
Set URL="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Best of Avicii Megamix 2014.mp3"
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[5] Play Mega Mix 90
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching Mega Mix 90 ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\IbizaMix.vbs
Set URL="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Megamix 90.mp3"
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[6] Stop the music
cls & color 0C
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo  %x% Please Wait for a while .. Stopping the music ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:Play
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>%~2
::*********************************************************************************************
:Tab
set "x="
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Set "x=!x!    "
REM                                  ^-- this is a TAB
goto :eof
::*********************************************************************************************
:SkipLine
    For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Echo(
    Goto:Eof
:EOF
EXIT
::*********************************************************************************************
```