# Playing Sound In Batch

Tags: batch-file

is there a way to open a mp3 from batch without it making a window, i use a start command but it opens up a window which would get anoying in the game im playing

cls
color 02
START doSominSound.mp3

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418730/batch-file-to-play-a-song/20422720#20422720

Comment: i tryed the minimize tool but it dosnt work

Comment: Just put the name of your file in this line : `set file=YOUR_FILE.mp3` and run `playsound.bat`