# How to play a .wav file in the background of a running Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, audio, command-prompt

I am creating a batch file and I would like to have a .wav file to play on command in the background when I am running the batch file in command prompt. I would like to have it so no other app is opened to play the file and for it to play right out of command prompt. Is there any possible solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: This is not technically supported by cmd. But you can use other technology built into Windows to kinda hack it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313709/play-invisible-music-with-batch-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File To Play A Song](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418730/batch-file-to-play-a-song)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

You can change the variable ***sound*** to your `.wav` path

For example you can set like this : `Set "sound=C:\windows\Media\tada.wav"`

```dos
@echo off
Mode con cols=50 lines=3
Title Playing DJ Buzz Radio by Hackoo
:Play DJ Buzz Radio
cls & color 0A
echo(
Set "Sound=http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
Rem Set "Sound=C:\windows\Media\tada.wav"
echo            Playing Now DJ Buzz Radio ...
Call :Play "%Sound%" 
::*******************************************************
:Play <sound>
set "_vbs=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>"%_vbs%"
cscript /nologo "%_vbs%"
::*******************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked very well for me. All you have to do is change C:\Windows\Media\Windows Critical Stop.wav to whatever your file name is.

```
@echo off


title ERROR

::"setting up" error sound - creating vbs file to make sound
set "file=C:\Windows\Media\Windows Critical Stop.wav"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
  
  ::playing sound
start /min sound.vbs

::wait 1 second for vbs to let go of file
ping n- 1 127.0.0.1>nul

::delete vbs file
del sound.vbs
```