# How to close an invisible VBS file

Tags: batch-file, audio, vbscript, invisible

I am trying to code a batch file that can play a song.
Luckily I found a [solution to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418730/batch-file-to-play-a-song) at Stack Overflow. I used SachaDee's method, which created a VBS file that would play my mp3 file nicely.

My only issue is that once the VBS file is opened, I can't seem to find a way to stop the music. I even tried deleting the file in mid-song, but the song will still continue.

EDIT:
I found out that the way to solve this is by running the following command.

```
taskkill /IM wscript.exe /F
```

Comment: You can't hide the task from Task Manager.  Find it in there and stop it.

Comment: But... it isn't in the Task Manager??
I know I sound like a very big noob at coding, but I very well know how the task manager works.
Also, is there a way to shut it down by code? Very helpful if it's in batch file code.

Comment: look for either the `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` process and stop that.  VBScript usually executes as one or the other.

Comment: I JUST found that out and was about to come back here and tell yall' :D

Comment: Pretty much all scripting languages have a run time compiler or shell that they run under.  cscript.exe, cmd.exe, bash, perl, python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to end up the question.

---

```
taskkill /IM wscript.exe /F
```

This will stop `wscript.exe` with full force. However, a `vbs` can also be executed through `cscript.exe`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript) question, it seems to be ideal to use `cscript` for command-line, to execute `VBS`. Altough both works.

Answer (score 0):

With your keyboard, press `Ctrl+alt+del` , then click ***Task Manager***.

In task manager, click on the section where it shows you the programs that are running.

Find the VBS icon: A little cube with branches.

Click on the icon, then on the ***End Task*** Button.